# Odoo: Check if a module is installed

Tags: python, model, odoo, decorator

I want to check if a module in odoo13 is installed. When I print an invoice I want to check in that moment. This is the code i have so far.

```
class Moduletest(models.Model):
    _inherit = "account.move"


    module_manufacturer_installed = fields.Boolean(
        compute='_compute_module_manufacturer_installed',
        string='Is Module installed?',
    )

    @api.constrains
    def _compute_module_manufacturer_installed(self):
        print('##############################**************************')
        module_manufacturer_installed = False
        for record in self:
            module = self.env['ir.module.module'].search([
                ('name', '=', 'product_manufacturer')
            ])
            if module and module.state == 'installed':
                record.update({
                    'module_manufacturer_installed': True,
                })
```

I made a field and want to check the status of the module. The function is working I have tested it in other models so i guess either I am inheriting wrong model here "account.move" or my decorator is not working correct. Can anyone advise.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

For compute fields use `api.depends` not `api.constrains`, and when you use depends you should at least call it without any arguments `api.depends()` if you don't have any dependency on any field:

```
module_manufacturer_installed = fields.Boolean(
                           compute='_compute_module_manufacturer_installed',
                           string='Is Module installed?')

@api.depends()
def _compute_module_manufacturer_installed(self):
    # don't repeat the same search for every record the result will not be changed
    module = self.env['ir.module.module'].search([
            ('name', '=', 'product_manufacturer')
        ])
    module_manufacturer_installed = True if module and module.state == 'installed' else False
    for record in self:
             # no need for update when you set only one field just use normal asignement 
            record.module_manufacturer_installed = module_manufacturer_installed
```

`@api.constrains` is used to validate the the field value after updating it in the database, if the value is wrong an exception should be raised and this will cause rollback.

Comment: Thanks you for the answer, I tried as you said and again with a print after the function but somehow I am not entering the decorator...

Comment: Does th value of the field changes?

Comment: Yes i checked it in an other place and it worked.
I need to explain my problem. 
When i want to print an invoice it sould check if the module is installed becuase if the module is installed I want a manufacturer column in my invoice.
So i want to use a field to get the information if the module is installed or not and use it in my template as t-if='module installed'. But when I am printing the invoice nohting is triggered. So maybe i inherit wrong model or the decorator is not working in this case.

Comment: Try to show the field in the view for testing if the value is correctly installed. or extract this modification to anther custom module(addon) that depends on both module, `account, product_manufacturer` but it's up to you

Comment: yes I tried the value is correct I just can t trigger the function yet when i m printing an invoice... but thank you for all the help and your time

Comment: Can you put the code where are you checking this, is it in the temple or in python code.

Comment: when i write @api.onchange('invoice_date') and print(module_manufacturer_installed) he shows me the state of the module with true and false in the console everytime i change the invoice date. So the  api.onchange decorator works with the invoice_date id. But i want to trigger that when I pring an ivoice and i dont have a field for that to give and id for example. I found the
def action_invoice_print(self) function now in the original account.move model can i use that maybe?